# Why is my branch coverage rate and line coverage rate failing?

Tags: java, maven, testing, test-coverage, maven-cobertura-plugin

Consider the following code:

```
  @Test
    public final void testIsUnitInvalidSadCase() {
    boolean expectedResult = false;
    boolean actualResult = false;
    double invalidUnit = 0.0;

    testFuelUnitValidator =
        new FuelUnitValidator(
            defaultTimestamp,
            defaultFluids,
            invalidUnit);

    actualResult = testFuelUnitValidator.isUnitInvalid();

    assertThat(actualResult, is(equalTo(expectedResult)));
}

@Test
public final void testIsUnitInvalidHappyCase() {
    boolean expectedResult = false;
    boolean actualResult = true;
    double invalidUnit = 0.02;

    testFuelUnitValidator =
        new FuelUnitValidator(
            defaultTimestamp,
            defaultFluids,
            invalidUnit);

    actualResult = testFuelUnitValidator.isUnitInvalid();

    assertThat(actualResult, is(equalTo(expectedResult)));
}
```

This is the method:

```
public boolean isUnitInvalid() {
    if (Math.abs(unit) < 0.0) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

When I change the line as `if (Math.abs(smu) <= 0.01)` and the test classes as `boolean expectedResult = true;` for the first test then the maven builds up fine. But when I try to build with above code, maven throws an error as: 
`[ERROR] *className failed check. Branch coverage rate of 95.8% is below 100.0%
*className failed check. Line coverage rate of 97.8% is below 100.0%`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use 0.01 in the method under test, your *two* tests exercise both parts (return statements) of the method.  So, you get 100% coverage.

When you use 0.00 in the method under test, both of your tests only exercise the "false" exit.  There is no coverage of the "return false;" statement.  So you get less than 100% coverage.

Comment: Yup, i thought so, So can I decrease my line coverage rate and branch coverage rate from `pom.xml`